# How to dm all moderators in discord by discord.py, not only one?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have this code:

```py
async def report(ctx, member: discord.Member,  *, arg):
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(9999999999999) # Imagine that 9999999999999 is moderator role id
    members = ctx.guild.members
    await ctx.channel.send('Your complaint was sent to moderators!', delete_after=10)
    for i in role.members:
        await i.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} sent a complaint on {member.mention} with reason:\n**{arg}**')
        await ctx.message.delete()
```

The problem is that when I write `$report @user reason`, only one moderator receives this report in private messages, not all. There are 3 moderators on the server, and for some reason only one receives a message in the DM, and not all **3** moderators.
How to fix this? I would be very grateful for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `await ctx.message.delete()` out of your for loop. If a message is deleted and you're trying to delete it again it will throw an error.